# Qual o melhor tipo de compactação de arquivos para otimizar resposta de servidores?

Tags: linux, seo, otimização, gzip

Recentemente estive pesquisando formas de melhorar o desempenho do servidor, diminuindo sua carga e consequentemente aumentando sua velocidade. Encontrei diversos tipos de compactações e benchmarks comparando os diferentes tipos de arquivos compactados, porém todos testes realizados a anos atrás, gostaria de saber, atualmente:

- Num comparativo básico, por várias referências citarem o **gzip**
  como padrão, seria ele o melhor? Por que?
- Levando em conta não só o arquivo final compactado, mas outros parâmetros como seu tempo de compressão/descompressão, memória usada e taxa de compressão(tamanho inicial/final). Qual teria vantagem sobre os demais?
- Que recursos/técnicas mais poderiam ser aplicados(as) para melhorar o tempo de resposta de um servidor além das minimizações de códigos, melhorias de consultas *SQL* e aplicação de uma nova forma de compactação?

Comment: Compactação onde? Para que tipo de arquivo?

Comment: Compactação no servidor para todos tipos de arquivos(eu imagino, ou os mais importantes como imagens, js e css, seria interessante levar em conta os dois cenarios), me fundei no conceito de várias fontes recomendarem o uso do gzip para comprimir os arquivos para otimizar a velocidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É difícil dizer, cada caso é um caso. Sem medir não tem como saber.

Manter os arquivos compactados geralmente não trará benefícios, ainda mais em SSD.

Se o arquivo for de mídia provavelmente ele já possui uma compactação própria, não faz sentido compactá-lo, só irá piorar a situação. Ele tende ficar maior e perderá muito tempo.

Em arquivos estáticos que a compactação pode ser grande pode haver ganho, mas muito pouco. Pode ser pior. O tempo de descompactação pode ser maior que o tempo ganho na leitura. Se o arquivo tiver menos de 4KB certamente será muito pior. Menos em arquivos grandes raros os casos que haverá ganho.

O que ocorre é que certos arquivos devem ser entregues compactados pelo próprio servidor HTTP e o cliente se encarregará de descompactar, aí há ganho, mas o ganho maior é na transmissão e não na leitura do arquivo. Mas caímos no item anterior, o formato do arquivo que vai entregar é melhor compactado. Se for isto só pode usar uma compactação que o cliente espera e até onde sei ele espera só o [Gzip](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182564/101).

Mas precisa fazer tudo de acordo com o padrão web determina, não é só compactar o arquivo.

Isso nada tem a ver com SEO diretamente, pode ter no sentido de demorando menos para responder o indexador pode dar uma pontuação ligeiramente maior.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).